# 2nd order ordinary differential equation problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I would like to solve this differential equation and I am looking for the technique/answer

Consider a function $f=f(r)$

The differential equation is
$$
f'' + (a(r^{-1})-b)f'+(c(r^{-2})+d(r^{-1}))f=0.
$$
Boundary conditions $f(r=0)=0$ and $f(r=\infty)=0$.

Please help.

Comment: This one looks ripe for a Frobenius type solution.

Comment: The frobenius solution is crazy and very messy.

My guess is maybe this is a sturm louiville problem?

I tried LaPlace/Fourier transforms but I didn't find a solution.

Comment: Also, Frobenius leads to a 3 term recursion relation.